# Adding supervisor to report

Tags: titles, report

I want to add the name of my supervisor on a simple cover page.

This is my code:

```
%type de document 
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\author{my name}
\title{the title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: How can i add a third supervisor in a template latex ????

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If all you want is to add the advisor, just add it to the author, like

```
\author{It's me\\[1cm]{\small Advisor: A.D.Visor}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\author{It's me\\[1cm]{\small Advisor: A.D.Visor}}
\title{the title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\end{document}
```