# How can I make an author appear on a new line?

Tags: titles, author

I'm writing a research proposal and my proposed supervisors names are appearing on the same line as mine, which isn't aesthetically pleasing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Does the level of coffee drank in a day effect how fast I drive?}
\author{Jimmy Mocha \\
\par\and Proposed Supervisors: Dr Nescaffe Gold \& Prof Dowe Egberts} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does removing the `\par\and` work?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360311/adding-supervisor-to-report

Comment: @HerbSchulz I tested your proposal and it works for me (`-->` has the desired effect).

Comment: @HerbSchulz Perfect! Thank you